# Is there any way to send and receive message over websocket Synchronously in one thread

Tags: java, spring, websocket, callback, stomp

We are using a `spring websocket server` and `OKhttp websocket client`(java).
We are using `SimpMessagingTemplate` to send request message from server to client. 
And from other side response is expected.

Is there any synchronous method to achieve the same?